# How to communnicate between two child fragments inside a parent fragment?

Tags: android-fragments, android-activity

I have a parent fragment A with a linear layout that has a child fragment B and a scrollview C.

In fragment B  have a <kbd>Go</kbd> button .
All I want is to display some text in scrollview C when I click on the Go button.
I have already googled so much but every where 
Communication between two fragments inside parent activity is shown.
How to achieve communication between child fragments inside a parent fragment?

Comment: You could use a `LocalBroadcastManager` in fragment B and receive the message in scrollview C

Comment: thanks buddy...it worked...so simple solution